# How to hide keyboard in Custom UIView?

Tags: swift, swift2, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

I have UIViewController(FirtViewController) in my Storyboard...
In Swift file assigned to this UIViewController i add custom UIView

```
let customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

In this customView i have a textField.
In swift file assigned to this customView i have function:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
textField.resignFirstResponder()
return true      
}
```

But when i pressed "return key" my keyboard don't hide!

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever you added `customView`:

```
customView.textField.delegate = self
```

Next, on the line of `FirstViewController`'s declaration, add conformance to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Then, put the `textFieldShouldReturn:` in the view controller.

Comment: when i add this code i have a error: Cannot assign value of type FirstViewController to type UITextFieldDelegate?